# Kibana's index management won't update document count

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I started to work with elasticsearch and kibana using elasticsearch-dsl. I'm following this guide: https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#persistence-example

Everything seems to work fine. However, when refreshing the stats in Kibana's index management panel, the document count won't update until I perform a search (could be coincidental but I doubt it).

This is my code for inserting into elastic:

```
connections.create_connection(hosts=['localhost'])
for index, doc in df.iterrows():
    new_cluster = Cluster(meta={'id': doc.url_hashed}, 
                      title = doc.title,
                      cluster = doc.cluster,
                      url = doc.url,
                      paper = doc.paper,
                      published = doc.published,
                      entered = datetime.datetime.now()
                   )
    new_cluster.save()
```

Where "cluster" is a custom class that defines my index structure:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch_dsl import Document, Date, Integer, Keyword, Text
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections

class Cluster(Document):
    title = Text(analyzer='standard', fields={'raw': Keyword()})
    cluster = Integer()
    url = Text()
    paper = Text()
    published = Date()
    entered = Date()

    class Index:
        name = 'cluster'

    def save(self, ** kwargs):
        return super(Cluster, self).save(** kwargs)
```

This is the panel I'm looking at: https://www.screencast.com/t/zpEhv66Np
After running the "for" loop above and clicking on the "Reload indices" button on Kibana, numbers remain the same. They only change I perfom a search (just for testing) on my script:

```
s2 = Search(using=client, index="cluster")
test_df = pd.DataFrame(d.to_dict() for d in s2.scan())
```

Why is this happening?
Many thanks!

Comment: how many data nodes do you have?

Comment: well, this is for the final project of my master degree. The university gave us a cluster with one master and 2 slaves. However, I'm only using the master. Just because we don't have much time and things seems to work now with what I configured :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have 1 node (which is probably master and data) and in index management it says that your index status is `yellow` which means replica shards are not allocated (you can't have replicas if you have only 1 node, because replica means to put those primary shards on another node(s). If you want 1 replica, you need to have at least 2 data nodes). You need to set replicas to 0 for index to make cluster in status green again:

```
PUT /<YOUR_INDEX>/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}
```

As for index count, after bulk operation there needs to happen `flush` to write documents on the disk. From docs:

> Flushing an index is the process of making sure that any data that is
>   currently only stored in the transaction log is also permanently
>   stored in the Lucene index. When restarting, Elasticsearch replays any
>   unflushed operations from the transaction log into the Lucene index to
>   bring it back into the state that it was in before the restart.
>   Elasticsearch automatically triggers flushes as needed, using
>   heuristics that trade off the size of the unflushed transaction log
>   against the cost of performing each flush.
>
> Once each operation has been flushed it is permanently stored in the
>   Lucene index.

Basically, when you bulk N number of documents, you don't see them immediately, because they are not yet written in Lucene index. You can manually trigger `flush` after `bulk` operation is completed:

```
POST /<YOUR_INDEX>/_flush
```

and then check number of documents in index with:

```
GET _cat/indices?v&s=index
```

You can also force flush to happen every N seconds, eg:

```
PUT /<YOUR_INDEX>/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "1s"
    }
}
```

You can read more about it in [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/indices-update-settings.html#bulk), but my suggestion is to not worry about it if number of documents are the same as the number of documents you bulked, and use `Kibana dev tools` rather than `index management` GUI.

Comment: Many thanks Dejan!!! Awesome response. It's crystal clear now